# Wildcard searching with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

Essentially I need to search for a word which can end and start with different things but always contains the same content in the middle.

```
i.e. 345345hello356
     a0a0aphello553
```

I need to search through the registry for this key under:

```
HKCU\Software\[KeyBeingLookedFor]
```

So essentially, get the batch file to look through every key in HKCU\Sotware and if it finds it, spit out Key found via Echo.

Comment: Can you post the batch file code you have so far?

Comment: At the moment I have no code achieving the above, hence why I asked, I only have a batch quering a specific registry key in a known location rather than the above request.

Comment: `command |find /i "target string"` < This is one basic form which will filter out the `target string` case insensitively from the otuput of the `command` and display it on the console.  Use it to search for `hello`